# How to fetch data in edit or show method from method injection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have below code in laravel 5.2 in  TestController.php.

```
public function edit(User $user) {

}
```

When I call it with url "/test/2/edit" and print $user variable, it give me result of User with ID 2 , so I want to know how that is achieved?

I tried to replicate same in another Controller but I was not able to do that.

Comment: Check out [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: Post your code for the Controller that doesn't work and we can tell you how to correct it

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply.
@devk, Thanks , your ref. url helps. Now i get result from below code in my routes. php
oute::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\Models\Access\User\User $user) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user);exit;
});
But , how can i use that in Controller's method.
I want to use that in edit action as mentioned in question.
Thanks in advance.